# javascript errors do not show in the console when using autobahnjs

Tags: javascript, autobahn

If I generate an error inside the connection.onopen function, it does not get reported in the console when running using node:

```
connection.onopen = function (session) {
  console.log('Connection opened');
  throw('wobble');
  console.log('Bye now..');
};
```

**Console shows:**

```
node autobahn_test.js
Connection opened
```

So any errors in the code are very difficult to spot.
I've searched mailing lists, read the API and have tried to read up about promises swallowing errors - as I've a feeling that's what's happening here. But no luck so far.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: I found a reference to this issue here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/autobahnws/qzNEjfVo258/discussion you are on the right track I think.  Read through that thread, you will see a reference to whenjs and silently swallowing exceptions, and a thing called a reject handler.

Comment: I put the whole code inside the connection.onopen and connection.onclose into try-catch -- as workaround. I still wonder the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Setting gobal variable AUTOBAHN_DEBUG = true seeems to be the answer - thanks to the hint here
https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnJS/issues/117

The Autobahn webpage only shows this for browswer side:
http://autobahn.ws/js/reference.html?highlight=debug#debug-mode

So keys seem to be (a) Global variable and (b) Before autobahn code is included.

Repeating my original example but with

```
AUTOBAHN_DEBUG = true;
```

I now see:

```
AutobahnJS debug enabled
trying to create WAMP transport of type: websocket
using WAMP transport type: websocket
Connection opened
Exception raised from app code while firing Connection.onopen() wobble
```

Which is exactly what I wanted

Hope this might help others.

Mike